# Can I have SKSpriteNodes show up on a different scene during a transition

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am making a Game and have a custom transition I am working on. When you click the playButton on the TitleScene, it moves the the GameScene. Here is a gif of it.

[image]

Now I would like to have these buttons to fall *over* the other scene, or be seen on top of the other scene. So essentially the buttons need to be on the GameScene, even though they are part of the TitleScene. Here is my code for the transition:

```
let transition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Up, duration: 2)
transition.pausesIncomingScene = false
transition.pausesOutgoingScene = false

currentScene.view?.presentScene(futureScene, transition: transition)
```

I am unsure how to do this. Any help is wanted.

**UPDATE**

I have realized that the only way of doing this is to copy the SKSpriteNodes from the TitleScene to the GameScene. Check this code out:

```
func createTransition(transitionFrom presentScene: SKScene, to futureScene: SKScene, withTransition transition: transitionTypes) {

var yPositions : [CGFloat] = []
for child in presentScene.children as! [SKSpriteNode] {
    yPositions.append(child.position.y)
}
let topSprite = yPositions.maxElement() // finds the sprite closest to the top

for child in presentScene.children as! [SKSpriteNode] {
    if child.position.y == topSprite {
        var vel = CGFloat.random(-1, 1)
        if (vel < 0.3 && vel >= 0) {
            vel += 0.5
        }
        if (vel > -0.3 && vel <= 0) {
            vel -= 0.5
        }
        let fallAction = SKAction.applyTorque(vel, duration: 0.5) // slightly turns the Sprite

        presentScene.physicsWorld.gravity.dx = CGFloat.random(-0.3,0.3)

        child.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true // Become affected by gravity and falls

        child.runAction(fallAction, completion: {
            for otherChild in presentScene.children as! [SKSpriteNode] {

                if otherChild.name != "background" { //copies all Sprites except the background 

                    let copiedChild = otherChild.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
                    copiedChild.position.y += futureScene.frame.size.height

                    futureScene.physicsWorld.speed = presentScene.physicsWorld.speed
                    futureScene.physicsWorld.gravity = presentScene.physicsWorld.gravity //makes it so they have the same physicsWorlds

                    futureScene.addChild(copiedChild) 
                }
            }
        })

        let transition = SKTransition.pushWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Up, duration: 2)
        transition.pausesIncomingScene = false
        transition.pausesOutgoingScene = false

        presentScene.view?.presentScene(futureScene, transition: transition)
    }
}
```

}

This is what it looks like:

[image]

You can see that they don't line up properly, does somebody know something that I am missing?

Comment: I assume that all of the buttons and title on the home(a better word escapes me at the moment) view are SKNodes. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: @Dopapp No actually they are SKSpriteNodes (look at title)

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see that. Do you want the title ("Symmetry") to fall onto the next view with the round buttons too?

Comment: @Dopapp I feel that the only proper way of doing this is as appzYourLife said to copy them over, but something make them slightly off from each other.

Comment: This might not be worthy of a full answer so: How about having one *big* view––one where the height is double the height of the screen. The top half of this big view is the buttons/the initial view, and the bottom half of this big view is the game itself. The game is paused when the app loads. The play button unpauses it and initiates the falling of the buttons and title. The play button being pressed also initiates the big view moving up so that only the bottom half is visible instead of the top half. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Dopapp actually that's a great idea, the copying method doesn't work, that seems like a self explanatory method to getting it to work. Thanks.

Comment: @Dopapp and I thinks its worth a full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Scenario 1: One big scene

```
+------------+   }
|            |   }
|   Title    |   }
|            |   }
|            |   }
|            |   }   Initially visible half of full scene.
| btn    btn |   }
|    Play    |   }
| btn    btn |   }
+------------+   }  }
|            |      }
|            |      }
|            |      }
|            |      }
|   game     |      }   Half of full scene visible after play button is pressed
|            |      }    (the game)
|            |      }
|            |      }
+------------+      }
```

When `Play` is pressed, this big rectangle (14x19) shifts up so that instead of the top rectangle being visible, the bottom rectangle is visible. Because this is technically one big scene, the buttons/title can move freely through the both 'scenes' (it is really just one big scene).

### Scenario 2: Two 'scenes' overlap

```
             +------------+   }
             |            |   }
             |   Title    |   }
             |            |   }
             |            |   }
             |            |   }   Initially visible half of big scene.
             | btn    btn |   }     z-pos of the rectangle on the right is higher than
             |    Play    |   }      the z-pos of the one on the left, thereby allowing
             | btn    btn |   }     its contents to be visible above those of the gamescene.
+------------+            |   }  }
|            |            |      }
|            |            |      }
|            |            |      }
|            |            |      }
|   game     |            |      }   Half of scene and gamescene visible after play button 
|            |            |      }    is pressed (the game)
|            |            |      }
|            |            |      }
+------------+------------+      }
```

These to scenes overlap, with the bottom half of the rightmost scene matching up with the leftmost scene. When the play button is pressed, both scenes move up at the same rate until only the bottom scene is visible. In reality, the bottom half of the rightmost scene is still on top of the smaller scene.

The `alpha` of the bigger scene is `0`. For the top half of the big scene, you can add a background node; this setup allows the game to be visible and the buttons to still fall above the game.

To ensure that there are no issues with being unable to interact with the game scene because there is technically a scene on top of it (which may obstruct interaction), remove the bigger scene or change its z-position to be below the gamescene. This may not be necessary but in case it is... you know.

Remember that you cannot really embed scenes (At least according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596921/why-cant-i-add-a-skscene-to-another-skscene)), so you can't really use two scenes in Scenario 2. You can alternatively put the game scene in an SKNode or something like that as a work-around.

Comment: Could you check out my update to the question and tell me if you can think of something about it. Thanks

Comment: And something I thought about, I'd like to hear your opinion on it. What if the the TitleScene is twice as tall, but the bottom half doesn't have the colored background covering it. Would that half be transparent, and the buttons would could still show up on top. Or does it now work like that.

Comment: @grahamcracker1234, I don't think that I understand what you mean. I assumed that the colored background is a placeholder for the game. The way that I saw it in my head is that the buttons would just fall over the game so you don't need a cover in the first place. What is the purpose of the cover anyway?

Comment: @grahamcracker1234, also, in my solution, you don't need to copy the nodes because technically, it is all in one big scene

Comment: The red background is the Game, You are right I want the buttons and title to fall over the GameScene, but they cannot because they are part of the Title Scene, so I copied them onto the GameScene

Comment: @grahamcracker1234, the idea behind my setup is that technically, it is all one big scene. Therefore, no copying is needed

Comment: We can [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98626/discussion-between-dopapp-and-grahamcracker1234) if you want

Comment: Yes I agree, I moved it to one.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a copy of your buttons and add them to the `GameScene`.

Set the initial positions of the button on the `GameScene` equals to the last position of the buttons on the `TitleScene`.

Hopefully the effect will be the one you are looking for.

Comment: This was my original approach though it is always slightly off during the transitions. I am not sure why.

Comment: it is probably happening because you are missing a few update cycles between the transitions,  so make sure your copy happens immediately upon creation of your game scene,  and offset the numbers so that the nodes are in negative space.  This way it will appear seamless as 1 sprite, but what is really happening, is you are drawing the sprites on top of one another